# accessing https://api.twitter.com returns 403 error as forbidden

Tags: c#, twitter-oauth

I am trying to access https://api.twitter.com through my .net code using following code.

```
 var address = new Uri(TwitterBaseUri);
            var restTemplate = new RestTemplate(address);
            restTemplate.RequestInterceptors.Add(new BasicSigningRequestInterceptor(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret));
            restTemplate.MessageConverters.Add(new DataContractJsonHttpMessageConverter());

            string body = "grant_type=client_credentials";
            var entity = new HttpEntity(body);
            entity.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            var response = restTemplate.PostForObject<OAuthResponse>("oauth2/token", entity);
            _accessToken = response.AccessToken;
```

I don't see any issues while accessing it at home....but when ever I connect to my office vpn or access it at office)..it throws 403 forbidden error.

We got the access for twitter and we can access twitter.com w/o any issues at office. Can anyone help please.

Our test application is sending the following connect request:

```
CONNECT api.twitter.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The response is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Connection: close
Content-Length: 513
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to provide any authentication information while accessing Twitter from office, like a network username/pwd?

If yes, then you need to pass the same information in the request, to be able to authenticate your request over the vpn network.

A sample for the above suggestion is

```
ICredentials credentials = new     
NetworkCredential("Joe",SecurelyStoredPassword,"mydomain");
        math.Credentials = credentials;
```

Comment: No I dont have to provide any info like that.